# Your Jenkins workspace is almost full

Tags: git, jenkins

Jenkins has 12 different workspaces which take around 25gb.I think the problem is because in every workspace there is a copy from GIT repository which is 3gb.

Does anybody know why Jenkins is using different workspaces and why on every workspace Jenkins has a copy from the git repo ?

Probably not of the workspaces are in used. Is there a way to check which of them can be deleted ?

Answer (score 1):

Two questions, two answers:

1. For every build run in parallel, Jenkins will create a new workspace by default. 12 parallel builds = 12 workspaces. You can set it to share a workspace between multiple builds if you want, though how to do that is outside the scope of this answer because it's heavily dependent on your setup.
2. As long as there's not a build currently running, you can delete the workspace directory freely. Or you can just modify your build to have Jenkins do that for you. Jenkins will always create a new directory if it needs to.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian , Is this means that Jenkins is making with every build a new workspace ? For example if i delete all workspaces , in the next build Jenkins will create a new workspace without any problems ? I`m wondering if i delete all workspace , is there a change to corrupt Jenkins at all ?

Comment: Nope, you can delete workspaces 100% freely if they're not being used. What Jenkins will do is, if _no_ workspaces exist, it'll create a new one. After that, if it sees that the workspace is currently in use (running a build in it), it'll create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is not creating a new folder for each build by default unless running in parallel, but if you have 12 different jobs, it creates at least one folder for each job.

Anyway, you can delete a workspace at the start and delete it also by the end of the build (better do it only if build went ok since if it fails you may want to see the content of the folder for debugging needs).

Also, for each job, you can set the number of builds to keep or the number of days to keep, so this can reduce the number of builds.

Comment: Unfortunetely we have too many builds ,and some of the builds we are using 1-2 per year and some of the other builds we are using every week . I`m not sure that there is a generic solution, because every build has own story :)

Comment: I guess that what you refer to as 'build' is actoually a 'job' and for each 'job' you can set a different setting of how many builds to keep and/or how many days to keep